# Using APOC to import JSON data

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I used APOC to export a JSON file using the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (m)<-[r]-(p)
WITH COLLECT(m) AS mm, COLLECT(r) AS rr
CALL apoc.export.json.data(
 mm, 
 rr, 
 'c:/Book1.JSON', 
 null
) YIELD file, nodes, relationships
RETURN file, nodes, relationships
```

How do I import (not just load) this JSON file to another graph database using Cypher?

Comment: Why is "loading" not acceptable?

Comment: Loading just showing the data in file but when i match the data i find no imported data

Comment: [This section of the docs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.4/export-import/load-json/#_load_json_stackoverflow_example) shows an example of loading data from JSON and then storing it to the DB.